# send the output result to text file from import module function

Tags: python

I want to print the result output to the file without overwrite by import module (the def main function contains asking user input and calculation).  But after I run the import file, the file part didn't come out after printing the output from main function of module. The first part in import is to check for user input bad data.
module.py

```
def apple_amount:
    app=int(input('enter number:')
    return app
def price_apple(app):
    apple_price = app*2
    return apple_price
def banana_amount:
    ...
    return bana
def price_ban(bana):
    ...
    return banana_price
def main():
    apples = apple_amount()
    total_apple_price = price_apple(apples)
    bananas = banana_amount()
    total_banana_price = price_banana(bananas)
    total_price = final_price(apples,bananas)
 
    print('You bought $%d or apples and $%d of bananas. Your final bill is $%d.' %(total_apple_price,total_banana_price,total_price))



import module as fr
try:
    print(fr.main()) 
except ValueError:
    print("This is not a number!")
filename = input("Enter file name: ")
try:
    f = open(filename, "w")
    f.write()
    f.close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")
```

Comment: Please, [don't post your code/error messages as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4298200). Firstly we want to copy/paste it and secondly search engines are unable to index that information. So please make sure that any textual information is actually provided in text form.

Comment: sounds like you want module.py to return a string instead of print a string to standard output.
return "'You bought $%d or apples and $%d of bananas. Your final bill is $%d.'
  %(total_apple_price,total_banana_price,total_price)